# What is the word to represent a "rarely visited place"?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, synonyms

What is the word to represent a "rarely visited place"? Please suggest any words with that meaning; also, thank you.

Comment: "Suggest me" is not legal in English. You should probably visit our sister site for [ell.se].

Comment: I would vote to reopen if there were context.

Comment: A _hidden gem_ twins 'unfrequented' with value. But you need to give a sample sentence.

Answer (score 3):

***Unfrequented***:

> not often visited or traveled over
>
> - Constructing a modern port in an ***unfrequented*** part of Laos could help service a new tourist city. — Joshua Berlinger, CNN, 7 Dec. 2020 ([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unfrequented))

Answer (score 1):

fev's *unfrequented* is good. An idiom is

**off the beaten track** or US **off the beaten path**

> in a remote place rarely visited by people
>
> *The store is truly located off the beaten path, in an industrial
> park tucked away on a quiet road.*
>
> *I am always looking for trips that are off the beaten track and are simple, safe, and rewarding in the numbers and varieties of birds
> located.* [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/off%20the%20beaten%20track)